# EV3 switch block does not recognize text?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

i am using file access to input variables into my programm.
text file is something like this:
a
b
c
..

on each loop, program access file (using File Access block) and reads a new line "a" or "b" or "c" etc. and write this into a variable. I then use this variable as input for switch block. However switch block only recognized the very first character, while all others are very much all "false"

i know file access pulls out the information (i can display such input using the display block to show it..) yet for the switch block this information does not get recognized.

i tried with numeric, but i get the same problem..

Any ideas?

thanks!

[image: input text file]

[image: code - file access read input from txt file into a variable that is then used to display it on the screen one character at a time. switch is used to change size."B" should be bigger variables are displayed but condition of the switch is always "false"]

Comment: Welcome. Please update your post with a clear image of your code, or at least the relevant section(s)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have found a bug in the file block. I am guessing that the text after the first line must have the a hidden newline character or something like that that causes it to not the switch block values.

However, I was able to get it working with numeric values.

Sample `data.rtf`

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sample code: 
[image: EV3-G screenshot]

I also noticed that it doesn't work unless the file has Windows line endings (CRLF). If you are using Notepad in Windows, this is not a problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for this David - i guess i will switch to numeric as my list of inputs although think i tried that before and it gave me same problem.  Did you use usual windows notepad editor to create your data.rtf?

Comment: I tested on macOS using Visual Studio Code for my text editor. It allows you to select which type of line endings to use in the file.